# Interface conversion error while sending the payload for POST request - Custom Terraform Provider

Tags: go, sdk, terraform, schema, terraform-provider

I am working on creating a custom terraform provider by using terraform sdk. I am trying to create resource from the existing API POST call. I am finding it difficult to map a payload(which I am getting from terraform config file) required for sending the POST request. After running terraform apply, I am getting following error: `panic: interface conversion: interface {} is []interface {}, not []string` caused by this line from my resource creation file `CreateProjectPayload.Members = d.Get("members").([]string)`.

**Terraform file:**

```
resource "test_create_project" "project" {
  members = ["test", "test1"]
  metadata = {
    business_justification = "terraform"
    id = "45333422"
    description = "terraform test project"
  }
  owners = ["test"]

  tenant_name = "Test Name"
  workspace_name = "Test Ws Name"

}

output "create_project_details" {
  value = test_create_project.project
}
```

**Resource Creation File:**

```
type CreateProjectPostReq struct {
    Members       []string      `json:"members"`
    Metadata      Metadata `json:"metadata"`
    Owners        []string      `json:"owners"`
    TenantName    string        `json:"tenantName"`
    WorkspaceName string        `json:"workspaceName"`
}

type Metadata struct {
    BusinessJustification string `json:"businessJustification"`
    Id                 string `json:"Id"`
    Description           string `json:"description"`
}

func resourceProject() *schema.Resource {
    return &schema.Resource{
        CreateContext: resourceProjectCreate,
        ReadContext:   resourceProjectRead,
        //UpdateContext: resourceProjectUpdate,
        DeleteContext: resourceProjectDelete,
        Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{
            "members": &schema.Schema{
                Type:     schema.TypeList,
                Required: true,
                ForceNew: true,
                Elem:     &schema.Schema{Type: schema.TypeString},
            },
            "metadata": &schema.Schema{
                Type:     schema.TypeMap,
                Required: true,
                ForceNew: true,
                Elem:     &schema.Schema{Type: schema.TypeString},
            },
            "owners": &schema.Schema{
                Type:     schema.TypeList,
                Required: true,
                ForceNew: true,
                Elem:     &schema.Schema{Type: schema.TypeString},
            },
            "tenant_name": &schema.Schema{
                Type:     schema.TypeString,
                Required: true,
                ForceNew: true,
            },
            "workspace_name": &schema.Schema{
                Type:     schema.TypeString,
                Required: true,
                ForceNew: true,
            },
        },
    }
}

func resourceProjectCreate(ctx context.Context, d *schema.ResourceData, m interface{}) diag.Diagnostics {
    tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }
    client := &http.Client{Transport: tr, Timeout: 30 * time.Second}

    // Warning or errors can be collected in a slice type
    var diags diag.Diagnostics

    CreateProjectPayload := CreateProjectPostReq{}

    CreateProjectPayload.Members = d.Get("members").([]string)
    CreateProjectPayload.Metadata.BusinessJustification = d.Get("business_justification").(string)
    CreateProjectPayload.Metadata.CarId = d.Get("car_id").(string)
    CreateProjectPayload.Metadata.Description = d.Get("description").(string)
    CreateProjectPayload.TenantName = d.Get("tenant_name").(string)
    CreateProjectPayload.WorkspaceName = d.Get("workspace_name").(string)
    CreateProjectPayload.Owners = d.Get("owners").([]string)

    payload, err := json.Marshal(&CreateProjectPayload)
    if err != nil {
        return diag.FromErr(err)
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", fmt.Sprintf("%s/workspaces", "https://testapi.com/v1"), bytes.NewBuffer(payload))
    req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer xxxx")
    if err != nil {
        return diag.FromErr(err)
    }

    r, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return diag.FromErr(err)
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()

    return diags
}

func resourceProjectRead(ctx context.Context, d *schema.ResourceData, m interface{}) diag.Diagnostics {

    // Warning or errors can be collected in a slice type
    var diags diag.Diagnostics

    return diags
}

func resourceProjectDelete(ctx context.Context, d *schema.ResourceData, m interface{}) diag.Diagnostics {

    // Warning or errors can be collected in a slice type
    var diags diag.Diagnostics

    return diags
}
```

Comment: The error message states the string slice is the incorrect type. Have you tried fixing the type? Do you believe the error message to be inaccurate?

Comment: Yes, the type is correct according to my understanding. As members field is a list of string. Can you elaborate, if you mean otherwise

Comment: I think you need to call Get as an interface slice, then make a new slice of strings for the client usage, and cast/insert each element individually